# Contact form on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, contact-form

I have done quite some research and found that most people tend to post about using amazon lambda, SES to serve the e-mails.

What I have is an amazon S3 website with a third party domain from namecheap. I got a private @domain.com email to work. My site is purely html/css/java script (I purchased a template and made it suit my needs).

My template uses php for the contact form, which amazon S3 doesn't run.

Is there a way to use any other amazon service such as EC2, SES, Lamda to call to?

---

What I am gathering is the way it works is, when someone clicks "submit" to my contact form, some other service will pull that request, save the information submitted and then send it to me? Is this correct?

So what can I setup for that? I already own a domain, a private e-mail (@domain.com) and my site works perfectly on amazon S3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a system for "serverless" website that run javascript functions in the s3 hosted webpage, these then can call Lambda functions to do things like send emails with SES

Comment: Okay and is there an alternative way? For example, I already have PhP code for my contact form, is there a simple way to run that PhP code through maybe EC2? Or is that stupid and I should just build my own contact form using lamda/ses?

Comment: I've not tried it (I don't use PHP) but other people on my team found it easy to deploy PHP on Elasticbeanstalk

Comment: PHP requires a server that is always running like AWS EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, or Lightsail. The easiest of those to use would probably be LIghtsail. However any of those will be a server you have to pay for 24/7 just to handle an occasional contact form submission, which seems way overkill. It would be effectively free to host a similar thing on AWS Lambda, but would require you to learn a different skill set in order to set that up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lambda is a good solution for this. You'll only pay for actual usage and don't need to worry about uptime or load.

You can create a Python lambda function attached to an API Gateway endpoint and call it from your script. Be sure to "Enable CORS" on the API Gateway endpoint so it can be called from a separate domain.